# How to translate question in the Quora app

Tags: applications

Some time ago I could see a button allowing me to translate questions in the Quora app as I would go through them. However I now cannot seem to find it. Where can I find such a button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The button is still there, but it appears only if at least one other language is added in the settings.

**Note:** To add another language, open your profile, click on the 3-dot on the right below your picture. then `Languages`. Select a language to add.

To view the `Translate Question` option:

1. Open the question in your Quora app, then click `More`.

[image: IMG:]

2. Other options will appear among them `Translate Question`.

[image: IMG:]

Comment: Thank you. Could you please answer my other Quora questions on this site please.